# Почему приватные методы в интерфейсе можно сделать статическим? И в чём смысл этой операции?

Tags: java, методы, интерфейс, static, private

Начиная с `java8` в интерфейсах можно создавать статические (`static`) методы. А начиная с `java9` в интерфейсах можно создавать ещё и приватные (`private`) методы.

Но в интернете я прочитал, что приватные методы в интерфейсах могут быть ещё и статическими:

```
public interface SomeInterface{

   private static int doSomething(){
      //Реализация
   }

}
```

В чём смысл этого? Приватный метод и так нельзя переопределить в классах, реализующих интерфейс. **Почему нельзя сделать такие методы только `private`?**

**Дополнение**

Для тех, кто не понял: речь идёт о **приватных статических методах в интерфейсе**. К таким методам нельзя получить доступ из классов, реализующих интерфейс, они доступны лишь внутри интерфейса. А модификатор `static` **у метода в интерфейсе** испольуется, чтобы задать реализацию методу, но запретить переопределение. Речь идёт об интерфейсах, о классах я ни слова не сказал.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143185/discussion-on-question-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приватные статические методы можно объявлять не только в интерфейсах, но и в обычных классах. Эти методы можно вызывать из публичных статических методов, собственно, в этом и состоит их назначение. Например, несколько `public static` методов имеют общую часть работы. Тогда её можно вынести в отдельный метод, который они будут вызывать, но при этом такой метод может не иметь ценности для  человека, использующего наш класс (ведь он может выполнять чисто промежуточную работу), поэтому мы объявляем его как `private`.

В качестве примера можно рассмотреть любой utility-класс, например, `Collections`. Там имеется очень много `private static` методов.

Точно также дело обстоит и с `private static` методами в интерфейсах. В интерфейсе может быть множество разных `public static` методов, опирающихся в своей работе на какой-нибудь выполняющий промежуточную работу `private static` метод. Ниже приведу пример, как это может быть, хоть пример и немного высосан из пальца.

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    static void printListIfSumMoreThan(List<Integer> list, int sum) {
        if (sum(list) > sum) {
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        // этот метод выводит элементы списка, если их сумма больше, чем sum
    }

    static void printListIfSumLessThan(List<Integer> list, int sum) {
        if (sum(list) < sum) {
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        // этот метод выводит элементы списка, если их сумма меньше, чем sum
    }

    private static int sum(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .mapToInt(elem -> elem)
                .sum();
        // а этот метод считает сумму: его работа - чисто промежуточная
    }
}
```

Дополняю свой ответ подробными рассуждениями.

Зачем нам вообще может понадобиться `static` метод в интерфейсе? За этим обратимся к интерфейсу `Comparator`. В нём есть много замечательных статических методов, один из которых - `Comparator::comparing`. Он предназначен для того, чтобы выдавать нам реализацию компаратора, которая сравнивает объекты по указанным полям. Совершенно очевидно, что этот метод не должен быть ни абстрактным, ни дефолтным. По задумке он именно статический, и вовсе не зря.

А теперь вернёмся к моему примеру (код, приведённый выше) и представим, что оба статических метода `printListIfSumMoreThan` и `printListIfSumLessThan` так же совершенно обоснованно являются статическими. При этом мы видим, что для того, чтобы они выполнили свою работу, им нужно найти сумму элементов в списке. Вычисление суммы - явно одинаковая подзадача для обоих методов, так зачем же писать код дважды? Вот мы и создаём отдельный метод, в который выносим код по вычислению суммы элементов в списке, а в тех двух методах просто используем его.

Почему метод `sum` является `private`? Потому что по задумке пользователь не должен его видеть, этот метод чисто "наш", служебный. Почему он `static`? Потому что **статические методы могут оперировать только статическими методами**. Если бы он не был статическим, то методы `printListIfSumMoreThan` и `printListIfSumLessThan` просто не смогли бы его вызвать, вот и всё.

Так и получается, что иногда в интерфейсе могут понадобиться именно `private static` методы.

Comment: А почему эти методы нельзя сделать просто `private`?

Comment: @Зонтик а почему бы тогда и все публичные статические методы тоже не сделать просто `public`? Статический метод - это метод, который вызывается не у объекта, а у всего класса. Он не может оперировать теми методами или полями класса, которые не являются статическими. Именно поэтому "промежуточные" методы, о которых я говорю, тоже `static`.

Comment: @Зонтик дополнил ответ

Comment: А Я то раньше мыслил, что приватные метды вызываются из методов, которыеи помечены ключевым словом `default` и делать их статическими смысла нет, и совсем не подумал, что статические методы в интерфейсе друг друга могут вызывать...